# Canvas width height style

Tags: html, html5-canvas

How I can edit width and height? In the right side I have:

```
element.style {
    width:475px;
    height:713px;
}
```

I'm trying to put in CSS but it does not work:

```
canvas {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my problem and I want to make width and height 400px:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please show you html code in question. no an image.

Comment: usually, when asking a html/js/css related question, it's customary to provide a example in a site made for this specific reason, such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the inline style being applied to the canvas element. This will override your CSS file because it is directly on the element. Check out this fiddle for a better understanding of how CSS cascades: http://jsfiddle.net/Ex9Lc/

You will notice that only one of the canvas elements is resized by the CSS "file" this is because the other element has CSS inlined on the element itself.

Think of it like this... the first thing the browser will do is check the default styles for a canvas element and apply them. Then it will look at all the styles declared in CSS files and in `<style>` declarations and apply those styles... then it will look at the element itself for any `style=""`and apply those styles.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're declaring the height and width of the canvas element in two different places: the tag itself, and the css file.

The style attribute gives the canvas a height of 713px and a width of 475px.  The height and width can be changed either by changing the style attribute, or using the **!important** CSS declaration to override the HTML:

```
canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px !important;
    height: 400px !important;
}
```

Using this code will override the height and width of the canvas, as defined in the style attribute of your canvas element.